# Gaussian unitary dilation of Gaussian channels

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

I am starting with a few definitions. All these are standard and can be accessed from some quantum information or quantum physics books, for instance the books by [Holevo](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/9783110273403) or [Parthasarathy](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-0566-7). The question will be explained after a (unfortunately) long list of definitions (which can be considered as axioms).

1. A $n$-mode Gaussian state $\rho_g$ is a trace class operator in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where canonical position and momentum operators $q_1,q_2,\cdots,q_n;p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_n$ (satisfying CCR) has a normal distributions on a real line. For such states it is convenient to work on $2n \times 2n$ covariance matrix $S$. By Heisenberg uncertainty, it can be shown that 
   \begin{equation}
   S+\frac{\imath}{2}J_{2n}\geq 0;\quad \text{ where  }~~ J_{2n}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & I_n \\ -I_n & 0 \end{bmatrix}. \quad  (1)
   \end{equation} 
   $I_n$ is identity matrix.
2. A Gaussian channel is a (trace preserving - for trace class operators) completely positive map  $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, such that for every input Gaussian state the output is Gaussian.  In terms of covariance matrix this gives a pair $(A,B)$ where $B\geq0$  and a map $S \mapsto A^tSA +\frac{1}{2}B$, such for every $S$ satisfying $(1)$ so do the right hand side.
3. A result of [Heinosaari, Holevo and Wolf](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0408) gives that if the pair $(A,B)$ satisfies 
   \begin{equation}
   B+\imath(A^tJ_{2n}A -J_{2n}) \geq 0, \quad(2)
   \end{equation}
   then it defines a Gaussian channel. This is obvious and directly follows from equation $(1)$.
4. Any unitary operator $U$, which preserves Gaussianity (i.e. for all $n$-mode Gaussian states $\rho_g$ the output $U^* \rho_g U$ is Gaussian) gives rise to a $2n \times 2n$ symplectic matrix $L$ which acts on covariance matrices in the way $S\mapsto {L^{-1}}^t S  L^{-1}$. We call such unitaries as *Gaussian unitary* (Second quantization).
5. If a Gaussian channel give as in item 2 satisfies equation $(2)$ of item 3, then there is a unitary dilation of the channel as given [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/10/8/083030). This means given $(A,B)$ satisfying $(2)$, there is a $L\in Sp(2(n+l))$, where dimension $l$ has to be chosen suitably. Conversely, if there is a Gaussian unitary dilation of any channel, then it must satisfies equation $(2)$. This again is easy to see.

My question: Given any Gaussian channel i.e. given $(A,B)$, and **without assuming equation $(2)$**, can we show that there is a Gaussian unitary dilation? Notice that, this question is weaker the one in [the last reference](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/10/8/083030) because we are not assuming $(2)$. We are only assuming that given $(A,B)$, for each $S$ satisfying equation $(1)$ the output $A^tSA + \frac{1}{2} B$ also satisfies $(1)$. Any completely positive map has unitary dilation, but can we show that for Gaussian channels that unitary is Gaussian so that by second quantization we get the corresponding symplectic matrix $L$. I could not do it from the above mentioned materials. May be I am missing some point(s).

Sorry for making a long statement. I am not sure whether this is the correct forum to ask this question. I request moderators to shift/ copy the question in the appropriate forum, if necessary. Advanced thanks for any  comment/suggestion.

Comment: This is old, but in case somebody stumbles upon the same: Condition (1) is not the condition used in the paper - the paper uses the convention, where $S+iJ\geq 0$, i.e. the 1/2 is absorbed into $\hbar$. Then condition (1) and (2) are immediately equivalent and the question is futile. To see that this is the correct version of (1) have a look at Example 1.